# Floating Loan Valuation and Par Value

Tags: fixed-income

Why is it true that the value of a floating rate loan is equal to its par value at payment dates?

How can one show this mathematically? I want to understand this both conceptually and mathematically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every reset date, coupon rate is reset to current market rate & as we know that bond trades at par when coupon and market rates are same.

Mathematically, we just need to substitute coupon rate with market rate to price a bond on the reset date.

Comment: I don't quite understand your response. Can you please elaborate? Thanks